# CODEIGNITER - fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have a smtp e-mail configuration to send e-mail via Codeigniter as follows:

```
$config = [
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://cph.dnet.net.id',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_timeout' => 50,
  'smtp_user' => 'Myemail@domain.com',
  'smtp_pass' => 'MyPaSsWoRd',
  'smtp_keepalive' => 'TRUE',
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
];
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

If I only send a few emails it always works. However, when I send a lot of emails an error occurs like the following:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\sicuti\system\libraries\Email.php on line 2268
```

error is solved by editing "php.ini" in the value "max_execution_time" to 9999
.but codeigniter displays new problems like this:

```
fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown
```

even though my smtp configuration is correct, according to the recommendations in my cpanel

[image: Cpanel Manual Configuration]

If only a few emails will definitely work, but if more than 10 errors will appear, What should I change so that I can send multiple emails at a time?
Thank you, any response I appreciate.

Comment: The first error, while mitigated by changing the maximum execution time in PHP, should not be considered definitely solved. Raising the max execution time may severely impact your server's performance in the future, plus it only avoids errors on the PHP side of things. That said, `140D00CF` indicates that the OpenSSL socket was never opened or it closed itself and it's no longer available. Very possibly, this is due to keeping the socket open for an excessive time.

Comment: my suggestion: can you time with a stopwatch how long does it take for these errors to show up? If it's always the same amount of seconds, it may be a SMTP server's directive that's shutting down the connection. You could kill the socket and open a new one on every email, but this may introduce significant overhead. If you really need to send mass emails with a loop, I'd suggest you consider a mail delivery service instead of sending the emails yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a loop function to send multiple e-mails, which causes errors because I send a lot of emails at one time, so I give a redirect to every e-mail delivery so that the delivery works normally. The following loop function I have inserted the redirect function, and it works very well :

```
function index () {
  if (!empty($this->Leave_Model->count_all_leave_wait())) {
    $leave_wait_data = $this->Leave_Model->get_all_leave_wait();
    foreach ($leave_wait_data as $res) {
      if (date('Y-m-d')>$res->Confirm_Date) {
        $this->Send_Leave_Request($res->L_Request_ID); # Send Email
        $this->Leave_Model->update_lvd_confirm_date($res->L_Request_ID); # Update Confirm Date When Success Send
        redirect('Login_Employe'); # Redirect
      }
    }
  }
}

function Send_Leave_Request ($id)
{
  # bla bla bla
  $this->email->message('Bla bla  la  bla  bla...');
  $this->email->send();
}
```